# Правильно согласованы слова?

Tags: выбор-слов, согласование, точное-словоупотребление

Приглашаем Вас, Алевтина Ивановна, принять участие в научно-практической конференции и просим выступить на ней *как непосредственный участник конституционного процесса* / *как непосредственного участника конституционного процесса*.

Answer (score 1):

Правилен **второй** вариант (со склонением); без склонения в другом контексте возможно было бы "*вы выступите как непосредственный участник*".
Однако возможны еще и варианты пунктуации (с запятой перед "как" и без нее), влияющие на точный смысл высказывания, - в зависимости от того, является ли уже Алевтина Ивановна "участником конституционного процесса" (1) или таковым её сделает участие в конференции (2), связанной с "конституционным процессом". В первом случае акцент на "просим как кого (по причине того, что она известный участник процесса)", во втором - "выступить как кого (в качестве кого)".

> (1) Алевтина Ивановна, приглашаем Вас принять участие в
> научно-практической конференции и просим выступить на ней, как
> непосредственного участника конституционного процесса.
>
> (2) Алевтина Ивановна, приглашаем Вас принять участие в
> научно-практической конференции и просим выступить на ней как (=в
> качестве) непосредственного участника конституционного процесса.

Во втором случае не исключено, что А.И. известна не только как "участник процесса", тогда вариантом (2) ей предлагают в выступлении проявить лишь конкретную сторону ее дарования.

Comment: опередил )))) Но совпали по основным моментам.

Answer (score 1):

Согласование, конечно, требует родительного падежа: ***как участника процесса***

Но тут еще надо иметь в виду, что "как участника" не должно отрываться от слов "Вас" и "приглашаем", "принять" или "выступить" - в зависимости от смыслового акцента. "Приглашаем(,) как участника", "принять(,) как участника" или "выступить(,) как участника", а? Что имелось в виду? да тут еще и с запятыми могут быть вопросы.

Мне ближе такое понимание:
***Приглашаем Вас, Алевтина Ивановна, как непосредственного участника конституционного процесса, принять участие в научно-практической конференции и просим выступить на ней.***

Я таким оформлением подчеркиваю, что полагаю приглашаемое лицо именно участником а не "как будто участником". А еще лучше:

***Уважаемый Имярек Батькович! Приглашаем Вас, как непосредственного участника конституционного процесса, принять участие в научно-практической конференции и просим выступить на ней***